# IE History Tracking, IFRAMES, and Cross Domain error

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, cross-domain, browser-history, scriptresource.axd

So here's the deal.  We have a Flash application that is running within an HTML file.  For one page we call a legacy reporting system in ASP.NET that is within an IFRAME.  This page then communicates back to the Flash application using cross-domain scripting (document.domain = "domain" is set in both pages.

THIS ALL WORKS.

Now the kicker.  Flash has history tracking enabled.  This loads the history.js file that created a div tag to store page changes so the back and forward buttons work in the browser.

Which works for Firefox and Chrome as they create a div tag.

HOWEVER

**In Internet Explorer**, history.js creates another IFRAME (instead of a DIV) called ie_historyFrame.  When the ScriptResource.axd code attempts to access this with:

```
var frameDoc = this._historyFrame.contentWindow.document;
```

we get an "Access is Denied" error message.  ARGH!

- We've tried getting a handle to this    IFRAME and inserting the    document.domain code.  FAIL.
- We've    tried editing the      historytemplate.html file that flex     also uses to include      document.domain... FAIL.
- I've tried  to edit the underlying
  ASP.NET page    to disable history
  tracking in the    ScriptManager
  control.  FAIL.

At my wit's end on this one.   We have users who need to use IE to access this site.  They are big clients who we cannot tell to just use Firefox.

**Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Do you need the history management in the Flash app?  Is it being used?  You can disable it with a compiler parameter.

Comment: Why did you fail adding the `document.domain=` code to the `ie_historyFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

I understand it's a last-ditch scenario, but you should consider making the case that IE may not be possible to support.  You'll need objective evidence, some samples that clearly show the problem, and a well-rehearsed spiel about the benefits of remaining standards-complient instead of coding specifically to a (probably dated) version of IE.

It's never guaranteed, but if you can convince them that there are objective benefits which will lower both the short and long-term costs then it's worth trying--just remember that for many clients are concerned with the business-case and not the techinical case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but sending this header from the server might work:

```
// in PHP...
header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"',true);
```

I've used it for setting cookies from JS code in an iframe.